# Поле да/нет Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: wordpress, acf, слайдер

Есть сайт на wordpress, использую плагин Advanced Custom Fields версия 5.8.1.
С помощью этого плагина выводится слайдер на странице. Каждый слайд состоит из полей: заголовок, описание, ссылка, изображение.

Задача сделать, чтобы можно было отображать на странице только определенные слайды.
То есть, например, есть 10 слайдов, 8 показываются, 2 не показываются. Но включить и выключить отображение слайда можно было бы сделать в админке при редактировании страницы.

Мы в настройках плагина нашли поле "да/нет", выглядит как классический чекбокс, то есть надо сделать так, чтобы при условии, если галка стоит - слайдер отображается на странице, если галки нет - слайд не отображается. [image: так выглядят поля при добавлении нового слайда]

Разметка слайдера:

```
 <section class="main-slider green-line">
  <div class="container slider-container">
    <div class="main-slide">
      <div>
        <p class="main-slide-title">Гелиевые шары<br>для детей и взрослых</p>
        <p class="main-slide-desc">Большой выбор</p>
        <a href="/katalog/" class="btn pink-btn">Каталог</a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="main-slide-round">
          <div style="background-image: url('...')">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="main-slide-num"><span id="cp">1</span>/<span class="slide-sum"></span></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header-menu">
      <div class="menu-menu-1-container">
        <ul id="menu-menu-2" class="menu">
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-41"><a href="/katalog/">Каталог</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-37"><a href=" /dostavka/">Доставка</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-39"><a href=" /oplata/">Оплата</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-40"><a href=" /ceny/">Цены</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-38"><a href=" /kontakty/">Контакты</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>      
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Приведите код разметки слайдера.

Comment: Код разметки добавила

Comment: Ну конечно было бы хорошо видеть каким образом Вы туда выводите поля репитера, но давайте я тогда предположу) И я не совсем понял, что делает меню в разметке слайдера?

Comment: @Виктория не обращайте внимание на комментарий. Это просто проверка условия получения секретной шляпы **Helping finger**

Answer (score 1):

Имейте ввиду, что я не знаю имен Ваших полей которые Вы создали в ACF, потому я использовал условные по типу `your_slider` и тп. Вам нужно будет заменить их на те которые задали Вы.

В случае если в условном поле `show_slide` вернется значение `true` (чекбокс чекнут), то слайд выведется, так как сработает наше условие `if (get_sub_field('show_slide'))`. Так же можно для этой цели использовать оператор [continue](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.continue.php) но пример с простым оборачиванием слайда в условие `if` скорее всего Вам будет более понятен.

```
<?php if (have_rows('your_slider')) : ?>
    <div class="container slider-container">
        <?php while (have_rows('your_slider')) : the_row(); ?>
            <?php if (get_sub_field('show_slide')) : ?>
                <div class="main-slide">
                    <div>
                        <p class="main-slide-title"><?php the_sub_field('title'); ?></p>
                        <p class="main-slide-desc"><?php the_sub_field('description'); ?></p>
                        <a href="<?php the_sub_field('button_link'); ?>" class="btn pink-btn"><?php esc_html_e('Каталог'); ?></a>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div class="main-slide-round">
                            <?php
                            $image = get_sub_field('image'); // предположу что для изображения в настройках вы использовали настройки ACF по-умолчанию, где возвращается Image Object, а не ID.
                            if (!empty( $image )) : ?>
                                <div style="background-image: url('<?php echo esc_url($image['url']); ?>')"></div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```